# Vim - How to identify plugin raising errors

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

As per the title, is there any way to know which vim plugin is raising error messages (apart from disabling/enabling one by one of course)?
I'm continuously getting the error message below

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>59_clear:
line    2:
E803: ID not found: 4
```

but I'm not able to figure out which plugin is broken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run the `:scriptnames` command, and look to the line prefixed with `59`: it will give you the actual script which is referred by `<SNR>59_...`.